# How to format a number to an arbitrary amount of decimal places

Tags: xml, xslt

Im quite new to XSLT and looking at the decimal-format function im still having trouble trying to format a passed in amount to X decimal places?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

```
<xsl:template match="AverageQuote">
<xsl:value-of select='format-number( ?????? , "###,###.000000")'/>
```

Where ive put the question marks im trying to pass in the value of the context node (AverageQuote) . I tried '.' and [.] but i cannot get the correct syntax.

Comment: Can you show the xml you're using and what xslt you've tried?

Comment: See the answer by @Maestro13 which works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try . instead of '.' that is, just a dot, nothing more:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '###,###.000000')" />
```